# How to handle null in LINQ query for nullable int if value not found

Tags: linq

Here i am using simple list and one of the ageto string column is null

I am check in linq query if value not found then to return null. But value cannot be null error is coming up

```
var list = new[]
    {
        new { AgeFrom = "0", AgeTo="24"},
        new { AgeFrom = "70", AgeTo= (string)null}
    }.ToList();


var result = from r in list 
                 select new EmployeeDTO 
         {
           //AgeFrom Column is int? in DTO  
           AgeFrom = Convert.ToInt32(r.AgeFrom),
           //AgeTo Column is int? in DTO    
           AgeTo = Convert.ToInt32(r.AgeTo ?? null)
         }
```

Comment: You're converting `null` to `int`

Comment: but AgeTo column in DTO is nullable int

Comment: Doesn't matter what it is in the DTO, Convert.ToInt32() does not take a null parameter

Comment: This code works for me as is, I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
AgeTo = String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.AgeTo) ? (int?)null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(r.AgeTo);
```

Which makes your code:

```
    var list = new[]
    {
        new { AgeFrom = "0", AgeTo="24"},
        new { AgeFrom = "70", AgeTo= (string)null}
    }.ToList();


    var result = from r in list 
                 select new EmployeeDTO 
      {
        //AgeFrom Column is int? in DTO  
        AgeFrom = Convert.ToInt32(r.AgeFrom),
        //AgeTo Column is int? in DTO    
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.AgeTo) ? (int?)null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(r.AgeTo)
      };
```

Convert.ToInt32 can not convert null to an integer, that will always throw an exception.

Comment: Getting this error Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'int'

Comment: add explicit cast to the values being set: `(int?)null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(r.AgeTo)`

Comment: Yea, looked over the nullable property, thanks @BurnsBA

Comment: Getting value cannot be null error ...Argument Null Exception

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to change:

```
AgeTo = Convert.ToInt32(r.AgeTo ?? null)
```

to:

```
AgeTo = r.AgeTo != null ? Convert.ToInt32(r.AgeTo) : null
```

The statement `r.AgeTo ?? null` is an example of the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator), which, in your case, is essentially saying that if `r.AgeTo` is `null`, then use `null` instead. As this isn't what you were trying to achieve, you are in fact passing `null` into `Convert.ToInt32`, which is causing your error.